# JQuery next() addClass() one by one

Tags: jquery, svg

```
        var svg = document.getElementById("svg");          
        var isToggled = svg.classList.contains("toggled");     
        if (!isToggled) {
            $(".svg:first").addClass("svg toggled");
        } else {
                i++
                $(".svg:first").next(i).addClass("svg toggled");
        }
```

So basically, there are 5 svg tags with class and id named "svg", and I want to change the class name to "svg toggled" one by one. At the momoent, it only changes the class name for the first and the second svg, and then it stops after that.

How to add class name one by one for all the svg tags?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.nextAll([selector])` to target all the siblings after first matched element :

```
$(".svg:first").nextAll().addClass("svg toggled");
```

Comment: Can you post complete code for that, wanna see the whole loop you made so far

Answer (score 0):

The following changes to your `else` will add the class to the remaining elements with a delay of half a second between each

```
else {
    $(".svg:not(:first)").each(function(i, element){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(element).addClass("toggled");
        }, 500*i); // 500 is the delay in milliseconds
    });
}
```

Updated demo at https://jsfiddle.net/gaby/rh9t15r3/21/

Comment: @user2068889 updated answer with demo based on your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop to do something one by one:

```
// This creates an array of all the svg elements
var svg = $("#svg");

//Loop the svg-array
$.each(svg, function() {
    // Check if the current element already has a "toggled" class
    if(!$(this).hasClass("toggled") {
        // Add it if not.
        $(this).addClass("svg toggled");
    }
    else {
        i++; // whatever i is
        // If the current svg already has the "toggled" tag you do not have to add it, right?
    }
}
```